# Problem with 2D char arrays, program does not print

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm *struggling with 2D char arrays,* I want to create a list of trains, but it seems that something is wrong here since after I've registered 7 names the program will automatically close... Can somebody help me and explain me how to write the program correctly everytime? Thanks.
**NOTE:***the code is not finished yet*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>
#define N 7
#define M 20
int main()
{  FILE *fp;
   fp=fopen("Lines.txt","w");
    int i,n;
   char trains[N][M];
   char train[M];
  for(n=0;n<N;n++)
 {
     scanf("%s", train);
     strncpy(trains[n],train,M-1);

  }
  for(n=0;n<N;n++)
 {
     for(i=0;i<M;i++)
     {
         printf("%s\n", trains[n][i]);
     }

  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Surely it's closing because it is looping N times and N=7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having

```
 char trains[N][M];
```

the printf in

```
 for(i=0;i<M;i++)
 {
     printf("%s\n", trains[n][i]);
 }
```

in invalid because `trains[n][i]` is a char and you print it as a string (%s)

All the form including the *for* can be replaced by

```
 printf("%s\n", trains[n]);
```

Else you can write char by char but you need to stop when you reach the null char :

```
 for(i=0; trains[n][i] != 0 ; i++)
 {
     printf("%c", trains[n][i]);
 }
 putchar('\n');
```

---

You open a file but you do not write in

---

You need to test the result of the *fopen* to check the file was open

---

Other problem in

```
 scanf("%s", train);
 strncpy(trains[n],train,M-1);
```

The strncpy does not copy the final null char

Because you have

char trains[N][M];
   char train[M];

To use the intermediate *train* is useless and does not offer a protected (its size if not longer than `trains[x]`)

You need to check the return value of *scanf*, and to read up to 19 characters (M - 1) you can do that :

```
if (scanf("%19s", trains[n]) != 1)
  break;
```

You do not have the guarantee you read 7 trains so you have to change the loop after :

```
for (i = 0; i != n; ++i)
  printf("%s\n", trains[n]);
```

You can also use *puts* in that case

And if you want to also write in the open file

```
for (i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
  fprintf(sp, "%s\n", trains[n]);
  puts(trains[n]);
}
```

---

Finally your program can be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 7
#define M 20

int main()
{ 
  FILE * fp=fopen("Lines.txt","w");

  if (fp == 0) {
    puts("cannot open Lines.txt");
    return -1;
  }

  int i,n;
  char trains[N][M];

  for(n = 0; n<N; n++)
  {
    if (scanf("%19s", trains[n]) != 1)
      break;
  }

  for(i = 0; i != n; ++i)
  {
      fprintf(fp, "%s\n", trains[i]);
      /*puts(trains[i]);*/
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
train1
train2
train3
train4
train5
train6
train7
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat Lines.txt 
train1
train2
train3
train4
train5
train6
train7
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note if the name of a train has more than 19 characters it will be cut, example :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
train1
verylongnameofatrain
train3
train4
train5
train6
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat Lines.txt 
train1
verylongnameofatrai
n
train3
train4
train5
train6
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: In this case is still a string but not printed as a full one but as a composition of characters, am I right?

Comment: @AvengerScarlet if you use `%s` the argument **must** be a `char *`

Comment: how do I make it out as a char*? Sorry I'm new into this and it's hard for me

Comment: @AvengerScarlet look at my answer, I print as strong (%s) and as char (%c)

Comment: no `scanf("%s", trains)` is not correct because trains is a `char**` , not a `char*`, look at my answer I edited it and added a proposal for the full program; I also manages the error cases

Comment: thank you, but can you explain in the easiest way why for a 2D array I have to consider it as just 1 Dimension array?

Comment: @AvengerScarlet it is 2D array of characters, you can also say it is a 1D array of strings, and a string is a 1D array of characters

Comment: @AvengerScarlet all is clear ? I edited again my answer to add the case where the name of a train is > 19

Comment: yes it is, I'm going to modify my code and eventually I'll ask for other help.Thank you!

Comment: I need some other help on my last question, can you look at it?

Comment: @AvengerScarlet what is the question ? I answer to all no ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(n=0;n<N;n++)
 {
     for(i=0;i<M;i++)
     {
         printf("%s\n", trains[n][i]);
     }

  }
```

should be

```
  for(n=0;n<N;n++)
  {
         printf("%s\n", trains[n]);

  }
```

This is because in your char array `trains`, each row contains the string entered by you. When you do `trains[n][i]`, it tries to access a particular character inside the string.

If you want to print each character, try like below:

```
 for(n=0;n<N;n++)
 {
     for(i=0;i<M && trains[n][i]!='\0';i++)
     {
         printf("%c", trains[n][i]);
     }
     printf("\n");
  }
```

Comment: but why? At university I saw my teacher doing a 2D print with a int v[N][M], does it mean that between char arrays and int arrays there are some changes?

Comment: When they do v[N][M}, they print the char in the string now the string itself.